# Linux: Creating directories named by two merged columns from a file

Tags: awk, directory, mkdir

I have several hundred locations with ID numbers stored in two columns as .xlsx file.
Now I need to create single directories named after each line such as:

```
ID | Location
01 | 100  
02 | 101
03 | 102
...
```

Final directory names:

```
01_100
02_101
03_102
...
```

I used some commands that I found online, e.g. to merge the first two columns separated by '_':

`awk '{print "$0"_"$1"}' file.xlsx`

However, it does not work for me.

and to create directories from lines in csv format:

`$ cat file.csv | xargs mkdir`

That works if I store the initial file as csv, but the output looks like

`1,100?`

I'd be glad to get some ideas or tips to fix this.
Thanks,
Niels

Answer (score 1):

First, let's fix the `FS` so `$1` and `$2` will be created and you intend to use them.

If you have a single space, a literal `|` and then a single space, you would do:

```
awk -F' \\| ' #rest of the awk
```

If you might have tabs, multiple spaces, etc, you would instead do:

```
awk -F'[[:blank:]]+[|][[:blank:]]+' # rest of the awk
```

The string concatenation operator in awk is a space between strings. So you would do

```
{print "$0" _ "$1"} #(note the space).
```

Better still is `{printf("%s_%s\n", $1, $2)`

So you could do:

```
awk -F' \\| ' 'FNR>1{printf "%s_%s\n",$1,$2}' file
```

Prints:

```
01_100  
02_101
03_102
```

Once you have that, use it in a Bash loop:

```
while read -r dir; do
    echo "making $dir"
    mkdir "$dir"
done < <(awk -F' \\| ' 'FNR>1{printf "%s_%s\n",$1,$2}' file)
```

Or use `xargs`:

```
awk -F' \\| ' 'FNR>1{printf "%s_%s\n",$1,$2}' file | xargs -n 1 mkdir
```

Or you can call `system` from inside of `awk`:

```
awk -F' \\| ' 'FNR>1{system(sprintf("mkdir %s_%s\n",$1,$2))}' file
```